# replacing an img with a div str_replace

Tags: php, string, replace, forum, vbulletin

so Ive been trying for a couple of days to replace this img

```
<img src="$post[avatarurl]" $post[avwidth] $post[avheight] alt="<phrase 1="$post[username]">$vbphrase[xs_avatar]</phrase>" border="0" />
```

with a div.

I finally got a result using

```
$vbulletin->templatecache['postbit'] = str_replace('<img src=\"$post[avatarurl]\"', 'CRAP', $vbulletin->templatecache['postbit']);
```

which replaces the opening and src tag of the img like it should.

but I can't seem to get it to grab everything within the img tag, im trying to do something like

```
str_replace('<img src=\"$post[avatarurl]\".*/>', .......
```

but when I add that last part .*/> it stops working =(
what am I doing wrong, how can I get it to grab everything in the img tag =/

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the regular expression .*, then you have to call preg_repalce instead of str_replace.

If your string is like this

```
$string = '<img some stuff /><img src="$post[avatarurl]" $post[avwidth] $post[avheight] alt="<phrase 1="$post[username]">$vbphrase[xs_avatar]</phrase>" border="0" /><img some other stuff />';
```

Then an appropriate regular expression could be this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/<img src="\$post\[avatarurl\].*? \/>/', 'CRAP', $string);
```

Here I have protected the caracters $  [] because these have a special meaining in regular expressions.
Note also the ? sign after the .*. Always remember that regular expressions are greedy, they will go on and on gobbling all of your file.

Comment: very well explained and helps me understand a lot clearer, but some reason this is still having no effect. $search = "/<img src="\$post\[avatarurl\].*? \/>/";
$replace = "CRAP";
$vbulletin->templatecache['postbit'] = preg_replace($search,$replace,$vbulletin->templatecache['postbit']);  is the code im using

Comment: if i use /[^<img src=(.?*)^<\/>]/ for my search i get results, but they're repeating results =/ i think there might be an issue with the $post[avatarurl] variable too i cant get it to use that at all

Comment: In the $search variable you should use the single quotes, not the doubles one : $search='$somestring' and not $search="$somestring" , the $ sign must be retained as a literal one, not as some variable  named $somestring.